# How does CORDIC calculate functions besides sin and cos?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, vectors, logarithms, computer-science

CORDIC efficiently computes $\sin$ and $\cos$ with just shift and add operations and two small lookup tables.  Great, so we've got basic trigonometry.  However, every description I read of CORDIC mentions that it also can be used to calculate "square roots, multiplications, divisions, and exponentials and logarithms" without providing any explanation of how an algorithm for vector rotation can compute these functions.  Is there some other set of identities or algorithms for expressing, say, logarithms in terms of trigonometric functions?  I'm particularly interested in how CORDIC is used to compute logarithms (as in many calculators), but I've only found one hint of a description of how this is performed, and it is locked in [this article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1478786.1478840) which I don't have access to.  How is CORDIC generalized to other functions?

Edit: I found the identity $\log(z)=2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{z-1}{z+1})$ but I definitely don't understand it.

Edit2: I found the identity $\tanh^{-1}(z)=\frac 1 2\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$ which is similarly mysterious to me.

Comment: $\tanh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$

Comment: Also, $\tanh x= -i \tan (ix)$.